# Publishing .NET 4.5 ASP.NET website on IIS 7.0 yields an error 404 though the files exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I am trying to deploy my first ASP.NET application on a server running IIS 7. But I always get an error 404 when trying to open the page. I thought it might be a start page issue, so I entered a direct URL to a `.aspx` file inside the `wwwroot` folder, but that got me another 404. Next step was to set a start page in the IIS Manager to a certain `.aspx` file, which made the page open, but the URL shown didn't include the specific page, and I didn't see my bootstrap navbar (just links that should be inside it) nor my Infragistics components. (To give context, we just upgraded the server to .NET 4.5 this morning, but all other ASP.NET websites in the same or other application pools still work perfectly!).

I then enabled the option to see folder contents in the browser; opening the website then showed me all the files that were supposedly not found, but clicking on them gave me 404 again. For testing purposes I put a `.html` inside the main folder: that one I could click and open, as well as `*.css` files or images in subfolders. But as I said above: ASP.NET is installed and working for all the other websites. I checked the MIME things, there is nothing for ASP related files, but neither is there in the working projects. The handler mappings seem to be correct as well.

So what could the reason for this be? I am totally unacquainted with IIS, so I lack any ideas beyond simple googling :/ My guess would be something permission-related (the app pool it's currently in is using pipeline mode: classic; but again, the same as the working stuff) or another dynamic content option I missed. Or - since as soon as I manually define a start page to be one of the `.aspx` files, I see at least *something* - it could be related to extensionless URL's? When I manually enter

`myservername\myappname\StartPage.aspx`

the browser at least shows

`myservername\myappname\StartPage`

instead. But I can't seem to find an option to change this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue when I first started working with ASP.NET. I spent hours scratching my head trying to figure out what was the problem. After a fair bit of research this is what solved my problem. I added the flowing code in the web.config file.

```
 <system.webServer>

<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules> 

</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Where would I have to add this? I tried adding it to the web config (Intellisense told me it should be there), but nothing changed :/

Comment: You want to be adding it after the </system.web>

Comment: Hm, that's where I put it, but it doesn't solve the problem unfortunately. Seems to be another reason for me :/

Comment: The following link is what i used when i had the issue http://dotnetnsqlcorner.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/error-403-40314-404-after-deploying.html

Comment: Wow good looking out man!!  Fixed it right up for me after adding this.  I wouldn't have figured this one out for awhile...thanks a lot!